# Encircling, unconnected trace loop

Tags: pcb, layout, trace

I'm working on some boards layed out before my time, or anyone that I can ask why they were made this way. Very much learning as I go, and I'm confused by this.
They all tend to have this loop around the board.
It's not connected to anything.
Even a simple break out for a connector has this same loop trace.

Why? What does it do? Is this a good practice?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If its not connected to anything it serves no purpose electrically. Perhaps it indicates the board dimension or something.

Comment: It may have indicated where to cut the panel into PCBs.

Comment: So just a physical layout thing then, thanks. I had a touch of wonder if it wasn't something about shielding emf, but that makes more sense.

Comment: It's also standard practice (today) to leave 15mil/0.4mm of unused circuit board around the perimeter. Perhaps this blue ring is to force that allowance (or larger.)

Comment: Generally, that is the border outline. It is used to make where one PCB ends and the other starts on the bigger PCB board. Keep in mind PCBs are manufactured on a bigger PCB board. So you can maybe fit 6 of your PCB designs on one of these PCB material boards. Hence in order to know where to cut each PCB out from the big PCB material the boarder line shows where to break of.